# NASM+C hybrid program compiling for 64-bit on 32-bit machine

Tags: x86, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, nasm, 32-bit

I am working on 32-bit machine. I developed a hybrid program mixing x86 nasm assembly and C (using OPENGL library too). I have C code in file "main.c" and assembly code in file "asm.s".
I developed 2 versions of my assembly code, one for 32-bit platform and one for 64-bit platform. I use following makefile to compile my project for 32-bit:

```
CC=gcc
ASMBIN=nasm

all : asm cc link
asm : 
    $(ASMBIN) -o asm.o -f elf32 -l asm.lst asm.s
cc :
    $(CC) -m32 -c main.c -o main.o
link :
    $(CC) -m32 -o output -lstdc++ main.o asm.o -lglut -lGLU -lGL
```

And everything compiles fine. I have a problem to compile my 64-bit version.
I tried it step-by-step with commands:

```
nasm -o asm.o -f elf64 -l asm.lst asm.s
```

Which compiled fine and generated asm.o file. Next:

```
gcc -m64 -c main.c -o main.o
```

Which also compiled fine and generated main.o file. And finally:

```
gcc -m64 -o output main.o asm.o -lglut -lGLU -lGL
```

Fails and gives me results like:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglut
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLU
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am i doing wrong and how to compile it for 64bit ?

Comment: Do you have 64-bit versions of those libraries somewhere where `ld` can find them?

Comment: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.9.0, i have this only, how to install it for 64 bit ?